# Symfony login form

Tags: symfony

I'm new on Symfony and I'm trying to do a access login form for my app but when I try to logged, it only redirect me to the form login again and again. Before of that, I used HTTP basic form and it worked perfectly, but now I'm trying with login form and it's impossible.

Here is my code:

***User class (with doctrine):***

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * Persona
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="persona", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="dni", columns={"dni"}), @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="correo", columns={"correo"}), @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="username", columns={"username"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="id_localidad", columns={"id_localidad"}), @ORM\Index(name="id_lugar_trabajo", columns={"id_lugar_trabajo"}), @ORM\Index(name="id_puesto", columns={"id_puesto"}), @ORM\Index(name="id_grupo", columns={"id_grupo"}), @ORM\Index(name="nombre", columns={"nombre"}), @ORM\Index(name="prioridad", columns={"id_prioridad"}), @ORM\Index(name="apellidos", columns={"apellidos"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Persona implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dni", type="string", length=10, nullable=false)
     */
    private $dni;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nombre", type="string", length=256, nullable=false)
     */
    private $nombre;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="apellidos", type="string", length=256, nullable=false)
     */
    private $apellidos;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="telefono", type="string", length=256, nullable=false)
     */
    private $telefono;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="direccion", type="string", length=256, nullable=false)
     */
    private $direccion;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="correo", type="string", length=256, nullable=false)
     */
    private $correo;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="codigo_postal", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $codigoPostal;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="es_tecnico", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $esTecnico;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true, nullable=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, nullable=true)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Puesto
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Puesto")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_puesto", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $idPuesto;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Grupo
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Grupo")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_grupo", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $idGrupo;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\LugarTrabajo
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\LugarTrabajo")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_lugar_trabajo", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * })
     */
    private $idLugarTrabajo;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Localidad
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Localidad")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_localidad", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * })
     */
    private $idLocalidad;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Prioridad
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Prioridad")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_prioridad", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * })
     */
    private $idPrioridad;
```

***SecurityController.php:***

```
<?php

// src/AppBundle/Controller/SecurityController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render(
            'security/login.html.twig',
            array(
                // last username entered by the user
                'last_username' => $lastUsername,
                'error'         => $error,
            )
        );
    }
}
```

***Security.yml***

```
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\Persona:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        our_db_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:Persona
                property: username
                # if you're using multiple entity managers
                # manager_name: customer

    firewalls:
        login_firewall:
            pattern: /login
            anonymous: ~

        secured_area:
            pattern:  /
            anonymous: ~
            provider: our_db_provider
            pattern:    ^/
            form_login:
                login_path:  login
                check_path:  login_check
            #http_basic: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate


        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

    access_control:
        # require ROLE_USER for /*
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

***login.html.twig***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>-Incidencias- Acceso</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        {% if error %}
            <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
        {% endif %}

        <form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

            {#
                If you want to control the URL the user
                is redirected to on success (more details below)
                <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account" />
            #}

            <button type="submit">login</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any idea? Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Please mention properly whether your using `symfony2` or `symfony3`. Authentication procedure is slightly different on both versions.

Comment: @niyasc I didn't know that. I'm using symfony 3.1

Comment: add a route other that "/" for your secured area like this for example : "/admin" and change last line of acces_control like that : `{ path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_USER }`

Comment: Comment out the login_firewall section, the access control section and get rid of the first pattern element.  Provider goes under form_login.  In other words, copy the example in the documentation, get it working, then add your stuff back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this. Here is my security in case someone needs it.

```
security:
encoders:
    AppBundle\Entity\Persona:
        algorithm: bcrypt

# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    our_db_provider:
        entity:
            class: AppBundle:Persona
            property: username
            # if you're using multiple entity managers
            # manager_name: customer

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        provider: our_db_provider
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /

        #http_basic: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

access_control:
    # require ROLE_USER for /*
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Thanks to everyone!!