# Not able to login using a login form in Symfony 3.1

Tags: php, authentication, symfony

I've been following the tutorial on the symfony website (http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html) to add a login for my Symfony 3.1 project. It works fine with the HTTP basic authentication, but when I add form_login using the tutorial here (http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html) it keeps redirecting to the login page and not logging in.

Here is my security.yml:

```
security:
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                ryan: 
                    password: ryanpass
                    roles: 'ROLE_USER'

                admin:
                    password: kitten
                    roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'

encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

firewalls:
    login_firewall:
       anonymous: ~
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        provider: in_memory
        form_login: 
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
        logout: ~  
access_control:
- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Security Controller:

```
class SecurityController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 */
  public function loginAction(Request $request) 
  {

    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render(
        'security/login.html.twig',
        array(
            // last username entered by the user
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
        )
    );

}

/**
 * @Route("/login_check", name="login_check")
 */
public function loginCheckAction(Request $request) {
    ;
}
```

login.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
    <div id="login_form">
{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security')  }}</div>
{% endif %}

    <form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
        <p><label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" /></p>

        <p><label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" /></p>

        {#
            If you want to control the URL the user
            is redirected to on success (more details below)
            <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account" />
        #}

        <p><button type="submit">login</button></p>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The tutorial does not flow as nicely as it perhaps should.  Your firewall definitions are screwed up.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767102/symfony-login-form#comment64906068_38767102

Comment: Yeah, they do seem a bit overly complex and messy. Looks like putting the encoders above the providers and removing the anon for /login in the firewalls section worked

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Cerad I put my encoders section above my providers and removed the firewall for the login

security is now:

```
security:
  encoders:
     Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
  providers:
     in_memory:
       memory:
          users:
            ryan: 
                password: ryanpass
                roles: 'ROLE_USER'

             admin:
                password: kitten
                roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'



  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false

    main:
     form_login: 
        login_path: /login
        check_path: /login_check
     logout: ~  
  access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

The login page is anonymous via the access_control list instead of a firewall rule